# Python script imported from another module

Tags: python

I have a `mymodyle.py` module that contains a function called `main`:

```
def main(event):
    parser = Parse(event)
    parsed_event = parser.parse()
    return parsed_event

if __name__ == '__main__':
    event = "ABCD"
    main(event)
```

This function will be called from another module:

```
import mymodule
```

And the `main` function will be called via `mymodule.main(event)` - it will pass the event as an argument to main function of `mymodule` module.

If I run it from another module, do I need to add the dunder at the end because it won't be called anyway :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
        event = "ABCD"
        main(event)
```

Another question: Do I need to add the `else` given that it will be called from another module?

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
            event = "ABCD"
            main(event)
else:
    //DO SOMETHING
```

Comment: If you don't want the module to be callable by itself, then you don't need the `if __name__` part. That's the point of that construct: *if* the module is executed directly, do something. Otherwise… don't. Therefore you also don't need an `else`, if you don't need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I run it from another module, do I need to add the dunder at the end because it won't be called anyway?

If you want your module to be both a "library" (`import mymodule`) and to *also* run your module with e.g. `python -m mymodule` or `python mymodule.py`, then yes.

> Another question: Do I need to add the else given that it will be called from another module?

No, unless you want to do something *only* if your module is imported from another module. That's very rare.